# Sharing Case Records with Customer Community Users

Tags: sharing, user, customer-community, apex-sharing, sharing-sets

We have set up the community in Salesforce and business use case is that whenever the case raises from the external user and assigned it to an internal user for resolution than any action or updates on that case record should be shared with the case created by user i.e community user to understand the status of individual's case.

1. OWD internal and external access is private.
2. The external user raises the case (Creation of case record in Salesforce).
3. Once the case is created then on some criteria the cases are assigned to internal users.
4. Now, the case owner is an internal user and now that case should be shared with the created user i.e Community user.

As apex managed sharing is not available for Customer Community license. How can we achieve this requirement?

Comment: You need to start with your OWD - what is your Internal and External OWD. And I don't see a reason why you cannot use apex sharing here. Its just that *AccountShare* and *ContactShare* objects are not available but you can still write custom apex here without any issues for any sharing requirements. This is very standard requirement.

Comment: @JayantDas Apex sharing is not available for Customer Community users.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced a similar issue to share cases created by external users and routed to internal users.

There are Sharing sets in Community Settings. You can play around with that and set up access to Case by Contact matching to community User Contact.
To do so:

1. Go to Community Settings, sharing sets and create a new one
2. Select Case as a supported object and select profile of users to share with
3. Select a case and other objects to share
4. Setup share rules